# The examine command in GDB confusion

Tags: gdb

When typing the examine command:

```
x/10xb 0xbffff450
```

It showed:

```
0xbffff450 : 8 bytes
0xbffff458 : 2 bytes
```

While typing:

```
x/10xw 0xbffff450
```

It shows:

```
0xbffff450 : 4 words
0xbffff460 : 4 words
0xbffff470 : 2 words
```

My questions are: 
Why in the 1st case the next address was `0xbffff458` and in the 2nd was `0xbffff460`?
Where is the in between addresses, I mean `0xbffff451,0xbffff452,`...etc?

Answer (score -2):

`x/10xb $some_address` shows the values at `$some_address` and 9 successive address locations incremented by byte as indicated by `b` in `10xb`.

`x/10xw $some_address` on the other hand shows the values at `$some_address` and 9 successive address locations incremented by word length which is usually `4 bytes` as indicated by `w`.

Coming back to your first question, it isn't like `0xbffff458` is the next address to `0xbffff450`. The address shown on left is just indicative and corresponds to the first value seen on right. It is just a style of output and nothing else. Note that the word length is 4 bytes, so if 4 word values are shown starting from `0xbffff450`, the next value corresponds to `0xbffff460` in hexadecimal format.

As for your 2nd question, those addresses are pretty much there and you can see their values by using examine.
Hope this helps!